# Multiple activities, identical onCreateOptionsMenu, onOptionsItemSelected and onKeyDown. Can I somehow reuse the code?

Tags: android, android-activity

Multiple activities have identical  onCreateOptionsMenu, onOptionsItemSelected and onKeyDown. When I implement a change, I have to do it in every activity (work time * activity count). Is there a way to reuse the code (for example write all of the three methods in one place and put down a reference to it in every activity)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure, just create your own `Activity` class that all your classes inherit from.

A bit like this - create an abstract base class that inherits from `Activity` and implements common behaviour:

```
public abstract class MyBaseActivity extends Activity {
    public Menu onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        /* do common menu stuff */
    }
}
```

Then make your individual activities inherit from your base class:

```
public class MyActivity extends MyBaseActivity {
    // inherits behaviour from MyBaseActivity
    // so don't need to re-implement onCreateOptionsMenu
}
```

Comment: Of course, thank you! Both answers are correct and written on the exact time, so I'm going to approve your answer as the right one (less reputation than @alextsc) and up vote alextsc answer.

Answer (score 7):

Sure, create a base activity and write your code in there.

```
public class MenuActivity extends Activity {
     // Menu stuff goes here
}
```

Then extend your seperate activities from that.

```
public class MyActivity1 extends MenuActivity { ... }
public class MyActivity2 extends MenuActivity { ... }
public class MyActivity3 extends MenuActivity { ... }
```

Comment: I can't accept two answers as correct ones so I'm just going to up vote yours.

Comment: No problem, we posted at the same time. I think Dave gave the better one here anyway (more details), so accept his answer. :)